# convert wpf to windows store app

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have written a c# application that I want to convert to windows store app and I know they are very similar but I absolutely have no idea how to start and what to do. 
Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/ ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I only have windows 8, but Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply not possible to convert until it is a [portable .NET application/library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

WPF applications and Windows store apps are of completely different beast.

If you want to migrate [Windows Store Apps: A Guide for WPF and Silverlight Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj984633.aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that I could reuse some of my code for the app. I read the 2 parts of the article and I also read all the documentation from Microsoft but the problem I have is that I don't know how to actually start migrating it. Like when you do pseudocode before coding to know what to do while coding.

Comment: See, Win rt API is completely different from WPF. They have some similar classes (very few), but their underlying architecture model is different. Win store API almost follows async pattern everywhere (not so common with WPF). Thus Migration is not a solution. complete redesign of application is required.